# how to insert records in relational model in relation to the first model(parent-model) database entities

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Here, I have two separate models 'User' model and 'Event' model. Event model is related to User mode. Now what i want to do is, when a user fills the event form and submit, then that event record should be created in relation to that user only.

views.py

```
class EventCreationForm(View):
    template_eventcreationform = 'eventcreationform.html'
    form_class = EventForm

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_eventcreationform, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        # data is here
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            user = User.objects.get(
                #######################################################
                #####            currently logged user            #####
                ###   what should i put here to get current user?   ###
                #######################################################
            )
            form.user = user.email
            event_name = form.cleaned_data.get('event_name')
            event_date_time = form.cleaned_data.get('event_date_time')
            event_address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            event.save()
            message = 'Event added'
            return render(request, 'base.html', {'message': message})
        else:
            message = 'Invalid form data, try again'
            form = self.form_class(None)
            return render(request, self.template_eventcreationform, {'message': message, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you might want to use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) so that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class EventCreationForm(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
```

You can access the logged in user with `self.request.user`.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        event = form.save(commit=False)
        event.user = self.request.user
        event.save()
        message = 'Event added'
        return redirect('/success-url/')
```

Note that it's a good idea to redirect after the event has been saved, to prevent duplicate form submissions.

Note that you are duplicating lots of the functionality of [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView) or [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview). If you use these you won't have to write as much code.

```
class EventCreationForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'eventcreationform.html'
    form_class = EventForm
    success_url = '/success-url/'  # form_valid() will redirect here

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(EventCreationForm, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I'm new to jango, so its better if i clear basics first and then will use shorthands.